# Unable to change partitions on my disks

Tags: partitioning, gparted, disk

I'm having trouble with disks on my machine. I'm unable to boot and currently trying to clean install Ubuntu. When I use Gparted with bootable usb disk, I can remove all partitions on my disk and when I hit apply button it says job is done but as soon as the success message disappears, it shows all the old partitions as they were before.

**Update**: when I use Disk utility, after hitting `-` button to delete any partition, nothing happens.

Comment: You of course have rebooted to verify this is the case?

Comment: You could just format the whole disk. You can also use the Disks application. Many people find it more user-friendly than gparted.

Comment: @David many times with no success.

Comment: @Nmath I updated the question.

Comment: Sounds like the failure to boot may in fact be a bad hard disk. Just a guess from experience. Can not boot can not edit partitions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resize partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions)

Comment: @N0rbert not really.

Comment: @David any way to confirm it?

Comment: Off the top of my head take it to another computer and try it there.

Comment: Check disk SMART using GNOME Disks or GSmartControl. Share screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

If you're fine with wiping ALL data on the disk, boot to a Linux live USB and try these:

1. Run this command to wipe the first few blocks of /dev/sdb

```
sudo dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/sdb bs=4M count=50 status=progress && sync
```

2. Reboot to the same live medium.
3. Create a new Partition Table ("gpt" for newer EFI systems and "msdos" for older Legacy Boot systems) using GParted.

Comment: I did it with no success. It seems to me any write operation to the disk won't work.

Comment: That means either:
1) The disk is damaged (hardware failure)t is read-only (some SD card holders and some rare kinds of disks, USB disk enclosures, USB-SATA etc., have a switch that makes them read-only).